# xml support in ckeditor framework

Tags: ckeditor, editing, html-editor, ckeditor5, xml-editor

I am evaluating tools for content editing ..and we are seriously looking for customization options for ckeditor. one major aspect which we would like to validate is.

XML schema support in ckeditor.. i know it is HTML editor, but i see through their documentation, that it supports XML transformation.

we are currently having XML editor, but it lacks flexibility in terms of customization.

I have queries. which i don't find an answer in their documentation.

- is ckeditor can be used as XML editor?.
- can editing content can be validated against XML syntax/schema?
- can we make CKEditor as xml editor through CKEditor framework?if so, steps to achieve.

any useful links would help us to proceed further.